# Problem syncing Calendar across 2 different Appleid's

Tags: calendar

My wife and I have seperate AppleId's. I am having a problem is syncing our calendar from my device(s) [iMac using OS 10.15.2, iPhone 11 using latest iOS] to her iphone 6S (version 13.2.3).  Tried sharing calendar, but have not succeeded. Can anyone help with this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add some details on how exactly you've set up sharing?

Comment: On my iMac I used my primary account.  Went to the calendar clicked share and added my wife's account.  Now that I'm telling you this it seems too simple.  It seems that this is not correct.  Appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: That's actually how it should work. Can you create a new (empty) calendar and try to share by adding your wife? She should get an email from "iCloud" afterwards, with a link she needs to click.

Comment: Can can also resend an invite from the same menu, in case the first one got lost.